# Check If Checkbox Is Checked and Display Dropdown Accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using a checkbox which hides a dropdown and shows another on being checked.

```
<dl class='fildLine'>
    <dd>
        <input type='checkbox' name='UnitListNew' id='UnitListNew' value='NewList'>New Unit List
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl class='fildLine mr'>
    <dt>Device :<span class='redTxt'>*</span></dt>
    <dd>
        <select id='device_new' class='dropDown'>
            <option value='' selected='selected'>---Please Select---</option>"+
        </select>
    </dd>
</dl>
<div class='clear'> 
    <dl class='fildLine mr'>
        <dt>Device :<span class='redTxt'>*</span></dt>"+
        <dd> 
            <select id='device' class='dropDown'>
                <option value='' selected='selected'>---Please Select---</option>"+
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class='clear'>
```

The Checkbox *UnitListNew* must hide *device*(dropdown) when being checked and show *device_new* .

```
$('#UnitListNew').bind('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkFlag = 1;
        $('#device').hide();
        $('#device_new').show();
    } 
    else {
        checkFlag = 0;
        $('#device').show();
        $('#device_new').hide();
    } 
});
```

But this does not seem to work as it shows both the Dropdown (on being checked or unchecked).

Comment: Umm...works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f3vNT/)

Comment: @I Can Has Kittenz - That's the frustrating part, it doesn't seem to have any logical error.

Answer (score 0):

Working version:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <dl class='fildLine'>
        <dd>
            <input type='checkbox' name='UnitListNew' id='UnitListNew' value='NewList'>New Unit List
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class='fildLine mr'>
        <dt>Device :<span class='redTxt'>*</span></dt>
        <dd>
            <select id='device_new' class='dropDown'>
                <option value='' selected='selected'>---Please Select---</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class='clear'> 
    <dl class='fildLine mr'>
        <dt>Device :<span class='redTxt'>*</span></dt>
        <dd> 
            <select id='device' class='dropDown'>
                <option value='' selected='selected'>---Please Select---</option>
            </select>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div class='clear'>
    <script>
        $('#UnitListNew').bind('change', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                checkFlag = 1;
                $('#device').hide();
                $('#device_new').show();
            } 
            else {
                checkFlag = 0;
                $('#device').show();
                $('#device_new').hide();
            } 
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing added, just check jQuery import and the order of the elements.

Comment: The question just have the code Snippet - which means a portion of the entire code necessary to understand the question. Your answer is neither helpful nor an answer altogether.Its the exact answers that gets down voted by admins.

Comment: As you were told by @ICanHasKittenz it's working. Each snippet works separately, I just put all together so you can check if you are missing something.

Comment: I told "check the order of the elements". If you declare your script before the checkbox is put in the DOM, the binding will never be attached, that's why I posted the entire code.

Comment: Try surrounding your JS code with `$(function(){ [your JS snippet] });` to wait until the document is loaded.